# Databases - Submitting data from inputs to database

Tags: php, database, forms, sql

I am attempting to submit data to a table I have created within my database.

For sanity sake I have called it 'wp_email_subscribers'. Including the wp_ prefix.

I know there is a way to insert data using the $wpdb but I would ideally be able to do this in a way that will allow me to copy this form over to other sites that are not WordPress powered. So was hoping to use a more traditional connect and insert / query to the DB.

At this point I cannot get the data to submit using either the $wpdb or a more classic method. Can anyone see where this is going wrong as I do not receive any error messages other than a boolean false value for $result. All other fields look like they should.

Enough rambling - here is the code:

```
<style>
#sign-up-form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(7,30,68,1);
    text-align: center
}
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        #sign-up-form {
            width: calc(100% - 40px);
            margin: 20px;
        }
    }

    #sign-up-form span,
    #sign-up-form input {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #sign-up-form input {
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    #sign-up-form .form-title {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }

    #sign-up-form .form-title,
    #sign-up-form label {
        color: #ffc90f;
    }

    #sign-up-form input[name=first-name],
    #sign-up-form input[name=last-name]{
        width: calc(50% - 5px);
        float: left;
    }
    #sign-up-form input[name=first-name] {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            #sign-up-form input[name=first-name],
            #sign-up-form input[name=last-name]{
                width: 100%;
            }
            #sign-up-form input[name=first-name] {
                margin-right: 0;
            }
        }

    #sign-up-form label[for=gdpr-consent]{
        font-size: 0.6rem;
    }

    #sign-up-form input[type=checkbox] {
        width: 20px;
    }

    #sign-up-form input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 210px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
        position: relative;

        border-radius: 15px;
        border: none;

        -webkit-transition: all .7s;
        transition: all .7s;

        background-color: #007dbe;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.875rem;

        cursor: pointer;
        outline: 0;
    }
        #sign-up-form input[type=submit]:hover {
            background-color: #00295b;
        }

    .error {
        color: red;
    }

    .success-log {
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: #4BB543;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>

<?php
    // show errors
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $servername = "****";
    $username = "****";
    $password = "****";
    $dbname = "****";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    // define variables and set to empty values
    $firstNameErr = $lastNameErr = $emailErr = $gdprConsentErr = "";
    $firstname = $lastname = $email = $gdprconsent = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["first-name"])) {
            $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
        } else {
            $firstname = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);

            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
                $firstNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["last-name"])) {
            $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
        } else {
            $lastname = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);

            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
                $lastNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
                $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["gdpr-consent"])) {
            $gdprconsent = "You must give consent";
        } else {
            $gdprconsent = test_input($_POST["gdpr-consent"]);
        }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    if (!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($email) && !empty($gdprconsent)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 'wp_email_subscribers' ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gdpr_consent') VALUES ($firstname, $lastname, $email, $gdprconsent)";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $conn->query($sql);

        var_dump($firstname);
        var_dump($lastname);
        var_dump($email);
        var_dump($gdprconsent);
        var_dump($sql);
        var_dump($result);
    }
?>

<div class="form-title">Sign up to our newsletter!</div>

<?php if (!isset($_POST["submit"])): ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>" class="email-sub-form">
        <input type="text" name="first-name" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>" placeholder="First Name *" required>
        <input type="text" name="last-name" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>" placeholder="Last Name *" required>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" placeholder="Email *" required>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr-consent" id="gdpr-consent" value="1" required><label for="gdpr-consent">I consent to $$$$ using my data for marketing purposes.</label>

        <div class="error-log">
            <span class="error"><?php if (!empty($firstNameErr)) { echo $firstNameErr; }?></span>
            <span class="error"><?php if (!empty($lastNameErr)) { echo $lastNameErr; }?></span>
            <span class="error"><?php if (!empty($emailErr)) { echo $emailErr; }?></span>
            <span class="error"><?php if (!empty($gdprConsentErr)) { echo $gdprConsentErr; }?></span>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])): ?>
<div class="success-log">
    <div class="success-inner">
        Thank you  for subscribing to our e-news.<br/>
        You have been added into our mail list.
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

This is me trying to use the $wpdb:

```
<style>
#sign-up-form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(7,30,68,1);
    text-align: center
}
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        #sign-up-form {
            width: calc(100% - 40px);
            margin: 20px;
        }
    }

    #sign-up-form span,
    #sign-up-form input {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #sign-up-form input {
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    #sign-up-form .form-title {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }

    #sign-up-form .form-title,
    #sign-up-form label {
        color: #ffc90f;
    }

    #sign-up-form input[name=first-name],
    #sign-up-form input[name=last-name]{
        width: calc(50% - 5px);
        float: left;
    }
    #sign-up-form input[name=first-name] {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            #sign-up-form input[name=first-name],
            #sign-up-form input[name=last-name]{
                width: 100%;
            }
            #sign-up-form input[name=first-name] {
                margin-right: 0;
            }
        }

    #sign-up-form label[for=gdpr-consent]{
        font-size: 0.6rem;
    }

    #sign-up-form input[type=checkbox] {
        width: 20px;
    }

    #sign-up-form input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 210px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
        position: relative;

        border-radius: 15px;
        border: none;

        -webkit-transition: all .7s;
        transition: all .7s;

        background-color: #007dbe;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.875rem;

        cursor: pointer;
        outline: 0;
    }
        #sign-up-form input[type=submit]:hover {
            background-color: #00295b;
        }

    .error {
        color: red;
    }

    .success-log {
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: #4BB543;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>

<?php
    // show errors
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    global $wpdb;

    /*
    $servername = "****";
    $username = "****";
    $password = "****";
    $dbname = "****";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    */


    // define variables and set to empty values
    $firstNameErr = $lastNameErr = $emailErr = $gdprConsentErr = "";
    $firstname = $lastname = $email = $gdprconsent = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["first-name"])) {
            $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
        } else {
            $firstname = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);

            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
                $firstNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["last-name"])) {
            $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
        } else {
            $lastname = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);

            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
                $lastNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
                $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["gdpr-consent"])) {
            $gdprconsent = "You must give consent";
        } else {
            $gdprconsent = test_input($_POST["gdpr-consent"]);
        }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    $table = 'wp_email_subscribers';
    $data = array(
        'first_name' => $firstname, 
        'last_name' => $lastname, 
        'email'=> $email , 
        'gdpr_consent'=>$gdprconsent 
    );
    $format = array('%s','%s', '%s', '%s');
    $wpdb->insert($table,$data,$format);
    var_dump($wpdb->insert_id);

    /*if (!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($email) && !empty($gdprconsent)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_email_subscribers` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `gdpr_consent`) VALUES ($firstname, $lastname, $email, $gdprconsent)";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $conn->query($sql);

        var_dump($firstname);
        var_dump($lastname);
        var_dump($email);
        var_dump($gdprconsent);
        var_dump($sql);
        var_dump($result);
    }*/
?>

<div class="form-title">Sign up to our newsletter!</div>

<?php if (!isset($_POST["submit"])): ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>" class="email-sub-form">
        <input type="text" name="first-name" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>" placeholder="First Name *" required>
        <input type="text" name="last-name" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>" placeholder="Last Name *" required>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" placeholder="Email *" required>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr-consent" id="gdpr-consent" value="1" required><label for="gdpr-consent">I consent to $$$$ using my data for marketing purposes.</label>

        <div class="error-log">
            <span class="error"><?php if (!empty($firstNameErr)) { echo $firstNameErr; }?></span>
            <span class="error"><?php if (!empty($lastNameErr)) { echo $lastNameErr; }?></span>
            <span class="error"><?php if (!empty($emailErr)) { echo $emailErr; }?></span>
            <span class="error"><?php if (!empty($gdprConsentErr)) { echo $gdprConsentErr; }?></span>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])): ?>
<div class="success-log">
    <div class="success-inner">
        Thank you <?php echo $firstname . ' ' . $lastname; ?> for subscribing to our e-news.<br/>
        You have been added into our mail list.
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is that a WordPress site, or just plain PHP?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż - Yes a WordPress website. c:

Comment: OK, so why are you creating custom mysqli connection? Should this data be stored in WP database?

Comment: Yes please. But I would like to be able to copy this to a website that is not using WordPress too (obviously would require different DB log in and DB names).

Comment: Sorry, but it's not possible. In WP you should use WP api to do this properly. You shouldn't create custom DB connections, and so on...

Comment: Please my you highlight how to do this?

Comment: I have added to my question my current attempt at using $wpdb

Answer (score -1):

I had a spelling error in my database that I for the life of me couldn't see...

I popped this handy line in to help me diagnose:

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
```

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Not sure why you have downvoted the query that has highlighted the issue with the code I have posted. Which is a fully working form template. Please rectify your hasty wrong doing.